# How much more cyclic vectors are there than hypercylic vectors?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, discrete-dynamical-systems

$\DeclareMathOperator\C{C}\DeclareMathOperator\HC{HC}$**Definitions:**

---

Let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a bonded linear operator on a separable (infinite-dimensional) Banach space and define the sets:

- $
  \HC(T)\triangleq \left\{
  x \in X:\, \overline{\{T^n(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}} = X
  \right\},
  $
- $
  \C(T)\triangleq \left\{
  x \in X:\, \overline{\operatorname{span}\{T^n(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}} = X
  \right\}.
  $

*When $\HC(T)\neq \emptyset$, then $T$ is called *hypercylic*.*

### **Facts:**

It is known (see Theorem 8.13 of [Grosse-Erdmann and Manguillot - Linear chaos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447121694)) that every separable Banach space admits a hypercyclic operator $T$.  Moreover, by the Birkhoff's Transitivity Theorem, it is known that for such an operator $T$, the set $\HC(T)$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$ not containing the origin.

### **Question:**

Suppose that $T$ is hypercyclic. What do we known about $\C(T)$ other than the fact that $\HC(T)\subseteq \C(T)$ (and in particular $\C(T)\cup\{0\}$ contains a dense linear subspace)?

More specifically: *How much "bigger" is $\C(T)$ than $\HC(T)$?*

-I leave the interpretation of "bigger" up to the reader.

Comment: You asked how much bigger is $\operatorname{HC}(T)$ than $\operatorname C(T)$, but I'm pretty sure it's the other way around.  I edited accordingly.  Also, that Amazon link is awesome.  It's the 2011th edition!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Also that's hilarious, I didn't catch that... they must spend a lot of time making versions haha